# method which take class and a instance of same class else compile time error

Tags: java, generics

method which take class and a instance of same class else compile time error.

something like

```
public void someMethod(Class classType, ClassType instanse )
```

e.g.

```
someMethod(String.class, "a instance of class") ==> compile ok
someMethod(String.class, new Integer(1)) ==> compile error
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
public <T> void foo(Class<T> classVar, T instance) {
    //....
}
```

And then call it with:

```
foo(String.class, "An instance!");      //Compiles
foo(String.class, new Integer(0));      //The method foo(Class<T>, T) is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>, Integer)
foo(Integer.class, new Integer(0));     //Compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

find solution like this:

```
public class GenericDemo<E> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GenericDemo<String>().classDemo(String.class, "abc");
        # new GenericDemo<String>().classDemo(String.class, new Integer(2)); # give compile time error
    }

    public void classDemo(Class<? extends  E> clazz, E e){

    }
}
```